# Prevent google maps flutter from rebuilding when switching the pages

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I have a very annoying problem of google maps flutter rebuilding after I switch the page of bottom navigation. I already persist the last zoom and camera position, however widget rebuilds itself every time I go on map page. How to prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

> AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin

For Example,

```
class _ExampleClass extends State<ExampleState> with 
AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<ExampleState> {
@override
bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, this worked very well and got an answer after 6hrs of googling.